# Replacing spaces with %20 in C

Tags: c, http

I am writing a fastcgi application for my site in C. Don't ask why, leave all that part.

Just help me with this problem- I want to replace spaces in the query string with %20.
Here's the code I'm using, but I don't see 20 in the output, only %. Where's the problem?

Code:

```
unsigned int i = 0;

/*
 * Replace spaces with its hex %20
 * It will be converted back to space in the actual processing
 * They make the application segfault in strtok_r()
 */

char *qstr = NULL;
for(i = 0; i <= strlen(qry); i++) {
  void *_tmp;
  if(qry[i] == ' ') {
    _tmp = realloc(qstr, (i + 2) * sizeof(char));
    if(!_tmp) error("realloc() failed while allocting string memory (space)\n");
    qstr = (char *) _tmp;
    qstr[i] = '%'; qstr[i + 1] = '2'; qstr[i + 2] = '0';
  } else {
    _tmp = realloc(qstr, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if(!_tmp) error("realloc() failed while allocating string memory (not space)\n");
    qstr = (char *) _tmp;
    qstr[i] = qry[i];
  }
}
```

In the code, qry is char *, comes as a actual parameter to the function.
I tried with i + 3, 4, 5 in realloc() in the space replacer block, no success.

Comment: To make your code work you'd have to add `i += 2` to the body of the if-statement. However, the code in my answer below avoids some other C string-handling traps that yours falls into.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

String-handling in C can be tricky. I'd suggest going through the string first, counting the spaces, and then allocating a new string of the appropriate size (original string size + (number of spaces * 2)). Then, loop through the original string, maintaining a pointer (or index) to the position in both the new string and the original one. (Why two pointers? Because every time you encounter a space, the pointer into the new string will get two characters ahead of the pointer into the old one.)

Here's some code that should do the trick:

```
int new_string_length = 0;
for (char *c = qry; *c != '\0'; c++) {
    if (*c == ' ') new_string_length += 2;
    new_string_length++;
}
char *qstr = malloc((new_string_length + 1) * sizeof qstr[0]);
char *c1, *c2;
for (c1 = qry, c2 = qstr; *c1 != '\0'; c1++) {
    if (*c1 == ' ') {
        c2[0] = '%';
        c2[1] = '2';
        c2[2] = '0';
        c2 += 3;
    }else{
        *c2 = *c1;
        c2++;
    }
}
*c2 = '\0';
```

Comment: If speed is preferred over memory use allocate a string with 3 times the space of the original string and skip searching for the spaces to determine the length of the new string.
Like the method found in the link in Kangkan's answer.

Comment: Good approach but you malloced string is one character too short (you don't count the trailing '\0') so it should better start with `int new_string_length = 1;`.

Comment: @x4u: Oops! Fixed it now. (Although I opted to change the `malloc` call rather than the initial value of `new_string_length`, so that the name of `new_string_length` remained appropriate for its purpose.)

Comment: @Daniel - why would allocating a block 3 times the space pf the original string be faster? `strlen()` has to iterate over the string anyway - why not just iterate yourself and account for spaces while you're at it as David's solution does? `strlen()` might be a bit faster than iterating yourself, but I'd bet the difference would be hard to measure unless your strings are really, really long.

Comment: @Michael - Sorry my mistake, I had in my head that the length of the string was known already. You are correct :)

Answer (score 6):

```
qstr[i] = '%'; qstr[i + 1] = '2'; qstr[i + 2] = '0';
```

That line writes three characters to your output buffer, so the next character you write needs to be written at qstr[i+3].  However, you only step i by 1, so the next character is written to qstr[i+1], overwriting the '2'.

You will need to keep separate indexes for stepping through `qry` & `qstr`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with David.

It is advisable to do it in two-steps: in the first loop you just count the spaces:

```
int spaceCounter=0;
const int sourceLen = strlen(qry);
for(int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) 
    if ( qry[i] == ' ')
        ++spaceCounter;

char* newString = (char*)malloc(sourceLen + 3*spaceCounter*sizeof(char) + 1)
//check for null!
for(int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) 
    if ( qry[i] == ' ')
    {
        *newString++ = '%';
        *newString++ = '2';
        *newString++ = '0';
    }
    else
        *newString++ = qry[i];

*newString = '\0';
```

Warning: code not tested.

Comment: note that `sizeof(char)` is required by the standard to be 1.

Comment: Also, you are putting a space into newString, which kind-of defeats the purpose of this function. It should be adding just the three character `%20`

Comment: @James: While you are correct, I think the possible intent here might be to make it more portable to Unicode.

Comment: James you're right, forget the space :)
I'm editing the answer to correct for this.

sizeof(char) can be two with unicode.

Comment: sizeof(char) is always 1. sizeof is defined in terms of char. char could be 8 9-bit bytes but sizeof(char) would still be one. Unicode is irrelevant as far as sizeof(char) is concerned.

Comment: sizeof(char) cannot ever be 2 in c/c++. It is required by the Standard to be 1. `sizeof(wchar_t)` might be 2.

Comment: +1 I find your solution a bit cleaner than David's.  Only problem is that you don't seem to be making a note of where newString starts before changing it.

Comment: @JeremyP: I'm not sure what makes this cleaner than David's - they're actually pretty dang close to the same. However, I'd have a few minor quibbles about this implementation compared with David's: 1) this one gets the string length and the number of spaces in 2 steps, David's does this in one step, 2) this one allocates more space than necessary - one extra byte per space found (which is certainly better than not allocating enough), and 3) this one loses track of the allocated buffer (as you mentioned). All these are easily fixed, but at that point you'd have nearly identical code to David's.

Comment: @Michael Burr: they are the same aside from the bugs.  I voted them both up to be fair.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning using the same counter I you will need to have 2 counters since the strings have different lengths

your else case assigns qstr[i] = qry[i]; after you have written the %20 you are at least off by 2 on the result string.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as url encode. You can refer to this page to see some similar implementation: http://www.geekhideout.com/urlcode.shtml

Comment: Oh no man. I am quite new to C and I would like to learn rather than using some predefined stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* toHexSpace(const char *s)
{
  char *b=strcpy(malloc(3*strlen(s)+1),s),*p;
  while( p=strchr(b,' ') )
  {
    memmove(p+3,p+1,strlen(p));
    strncpy(p,"%20",3);
  }
  return b; 
}
```

needs "free" in calling context.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function to do that;

```
String remove_http_header_space(String http_header) {

  while (http_header.indexOf("%20") >= 0){
    http_header=http_header.substring(0,(http_header.indexOf("%20")))+' '+http_header.substring((http_header.indexOf("%20")+3));
  }
  return http_header;
}
```