# Replacing spaces with %20 in a file on hard disk

Tags: c, file

I have gone through all the answers for the similar question posted earlier [Replacing spaces with %20 in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424474/replacing-spaces-with-20-in-c). However I'm unable to guess how can we do this in case of a file on hard disk, where disk accesses can be expensive and file is too long to load into memory at once. In case it is possible to fit, we can simply load the file and write onto the same existing one.
Further, for memory constraints one would like to replace the original file and not create a new one.

Comment: load in chunks of the file in section appropriate to your available memory using [`fread`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/)

Comment: do you mean you have a text file on your hard disc such that there's no space to make a copy of it?..

Comment: @Qnan exactly. if you can't make a copy. I want to utilize the same space

Comment: @simar as mentioned below, that's a strange idea and it's not easy to do. One thing I can suggest is that you split your file into smaller pieces that you will be able to make copies of, then process one-by-one in the usual fashion and finally put them back together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the replacement part, you can have two buffers, one that you read into and one that you write the translated string to and which you write to disk. Depending on your memory constraints even a small input buffer (say 1KiB) is enough. However, to avoid repeating reallocations you can keep a fixed buffer for the output, and have it three times the size of the input buffer (worst case scenario, input is all spaces). Total that's 4KiB of memory, plus whatever buffers the OS uses. I would recommend to use a multiple of the disk block size as the input size.

The problem is your requirement of reading and writing to the same file. Unfortunately this is impossible.If you read char-by-char, think about what happens when you reach a space... You then have to write three characters and overwrite the next two characters in the file. Not exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Horrible idea. Since the "%20" is longer than " " you can't just replace chars inside the file, you have to move whatever follows it further back. This is extremely messy and expensive if you want to do it on the existing disk file.

You could try to determine the total growth of the file on a first pass, then do the whole shifting from the back of the file taking blocksize into account and adjusting the shifting as you encounter " ". But as I said -- messy. You really don't want to do that unless it's a definite must.

Read the file, do the replacements, write to a new file, and rename the new file over the old one.

EDIT: as a side effect, if your program terminates while doing the thing you won't end up with a half-converted file. That's actually the reason why many programs write to a new file even if they wouldn't need to, to make sure the file is "always" correct because the new file only replaces the old file after it has been written successfully. It's a simple transaction scheme that doesn't take system failures into account, but works well for application failures (including users forcibly terminating the program)

Comment: Thanks, I knew the overhead of replacing thats why I considered asking..Do you mean when I change something in my GUI text editor and click save. The OS creates a new file, deletes the existing one and rename the new one with the same name as old??